# How to Add Texture a 3D Model using Helixtoolkit WPF Application

Tags: wpf, 3d, textures

//what code should i add to import image as a texture for my model 
//I have loaded the 3D model using this code

```
 ModelVisual3D device3D = new ModelVisual3D () ;
```

device3D.Content = Display3d (MODEL_PATH) ;
 viewPort3d.Children.Add(device3D);

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple. Use `MaterialHelper`.

```
string path = @"path-to-image.png";
Material material = MaterialHelper.CreateImageMaterial(path, 1);
yourModel.Material = material;
```